# Navbar keep going outside container

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

this is my first time using bootstrap, it seems that I didn't get why my items keep going outside of the container.
here's my current code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="frontend/libraries/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="frontend/styles/main.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="row navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-primary">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
                <img src="frontend/images/Logo1.png" alt="Logo Nomads"/>
            </a>
            <button 
            class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right"
            type="button"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navb"
            >
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navb">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mr-3">
                    <li class="nav-item mx-md-2">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link active">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item mx-md-2">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Travel Packages</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbardrop"
                        data-toggle="dropdown">
                        Services
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">bink</a>
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">bink</a>
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">bink</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item mx-md-2">
                        <a href="google.com" class="nav-link">Testimonial</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <script src="frontend/libraries/jquery/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="frontend/libraries/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here's my CSS

```
.navbar-brand img {
  max-height: 40px;
}/*# sourceMappingURL=main.css.map */
```

here's the screenshot of my live preview
[image]

and this is what I supposed to achieve
[image]

I have no idea if its my live preview settings or I'm doing something wrong

Comment: provide a working snippet here of what you have,  What you listed doesn't work

Comment: here, i use repl.it to compile it https://nomads.christokarna123.repl.co

Answer (score 0):

add margin:0; to '.container' div, it will fix it!

Comment: that's just make it fit, but doesn't change the fact that it still outside the container. also I'm actually needing it to have margin 300 on both side

Comment: I hope you find the answer now, First remove "row" class from the <nav> tag and add the following css to your main.css 


 .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-collapse {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
  
}